# posting nested json object in swift

Tags: json, swift

I have trouble while creating JSON object. My JSON is like below

```
{
    "user":{
    "accountId": 0,
    "active": false,
    "createdBy": 0,
    "createdOn": null,
    "emailAddress": null,
    "firstName": null,
    "gender": 0,
    "id": 9,
    "lastName": null,
    "role": 5
},

   "InLocation": "",
    "InLatitude": 18.5081214,
    "InLangitude": 73.8431377,
    "OutLocation": "",
    "OutLatitude": 0,
    "OutLagitude": 0,
    "InLocationNotFoundReason": "NetworkProblem",
    "OutLocationNotFoundReason": "",
    "sdate": "2014-12-10",
    "spunchInTime": "08:37:44"
}
```

I want to post this json object. But I am not able to convert this JSON into array and pass it to NSURLRequest.I used like below but it doesn't working:

```
 let params:[String: AnyObject] = ["user":["accountId":1, "active":false, "createdBy":0, "createdOn":"null", "emailAddress":"ramesh.golla@qlc.in", "firstName":"Ramesh", "gender":1, "id":0, "lastName":"Golla", "role":0], "punchInLocation":"null","punchInLatitude":0.0, "punchInLangitude":0.0, "punchOutLocation":"Unknown Location", "punchOutLatitude":0.0, "punchOutLagitude":0.0, "punchInLocationNotFoundReason":"NetworkProblem", "punchOutLocationNotFoundReason":"", "sdate":"2015-05-08", "spunchInTime":"10:02:53"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is to put everything into a dictionary, and use NSJSONSerialization to turn it into NSData. I can't quite understand why you would want to turn this into an array, your NSURLRequest will want NSData.

I wonder why you have a string here. JSON data should either come as NSData, or as a dictionary or array.

Comment: Yeah you are right but I am not getting way how to convert this json to dictionary or array. Please help.